# Convert number from float64 to Int64 is incorrect

Tags: json, string, go, floating-point, precision

I try to write a function, the code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Test struct {
    Data map[string]interface{} `json:"data"`
}

func main() {
    jsonStr := "{\"data\": {\"id\": 999804707614896129}}"
    t := &Test{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), t)
    fmt.Println(int64(t.Data["id"].(float64)))
    var x float64 = 999804707614896129
    fmt.Println(int64(x))
}
```

The result is below:

```
999804707614896128
999804707614896128
```

Why the results are 999804707614896128, not 999804707614896129.

Comment: Because 999...129 cannot be presented exactly in float64 (it's not arbitrarily precise). https://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 4):

Because `999804707614896129` cannot be represented exactly with a value of type `float64`. `float64` uses the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard for representing floating point numbers. It's a format with limited precision (roughly 16 decimal digits).

If you need to "transfer" the exact number, use string and not JSON number. If the number "fits" into an `int64`, you will be able to parse it "exactly" (else just work with it as a `string` or use [`big.Int`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int)):

```
jsonStr := `{"data": {"id": "999804707614896129"}}`
t := &Test{}
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), t); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

s := t.Data["id"].(string)
fmt.Println(s)
var x int64
x, err := strconv.ParseInt(s, 10, 64)
fmt.Println(x, err)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/DdCzSzxxM27)):

```
999804707614896129
999804707614896129 <nil>
```